# Query the DOM with multiple selectors in an Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have four classes that I want to perform separate but related style changes to. I would like to create an kind of two-dimensional array of the elements of each class in the appropriate array. I would also only like to do this once, right after the document is loaded, so that I don't have to repeatedly query the DOM.

Something like this seems to work. If I put `console.log( value );` after the variable assignment, I get the HTMLCollection in the console. But I can't figure out how to read from each variable in the array later.

```
var makeArrays = (function() {
    var borderClasses = ["inner-border", "middle-border", "outer-border", "shadow"];

    function getNodes() {
      $.each(borderClasses, function(index, value) {
        makeClassName =  "." + value;
        value = $( makeClassName );
      });
    }

})();
```

This is my original code. I'm trying to refactor it so that I only query the DOM once and then expose that result (and get rid of that `setInterval()`).

```
function changeColors() {
  var borderClasses = [".inner-border", ".middle-border", ".outer-border", ".shadow"];
  var replaceColors = ["green", "gold", "grey"];
  var selcolor = replaceColors[Math.floor(Math.random()*replaceColors.length)];
  var doIt = Math.random();

  function generateClass(myClassName) {
    var stripDot = myClassName.replace(/^\./, "");
    var createClass = stripDot + "-" + selcolor;
    return createClass;
  }

  function removeColorClass() {
    $.each(borderClasses, function(index, value) {
      $(value).removeClass( generateClass(value) );
    });
  }

  function addColorClass() {
    $.each(borderClasses, function(index, value) {
      $(value).addClass( generateClass(value) );
    });
    setTimeout(removeColorClass, 3750);
  }

  if ( doIt >= 0.33 ) {
    addColorClass();
  }
};

setInterval(changeColors, 7500);
```

Comment: FWIW, `value` is not an `HTMLCollection`, it's a jQuery selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
var makeArrays = (function() {
    var borderClasses = ["inner-border", "middle-border", "outer-border", "shadow"];

    var value = borderClasses.map(function (borderClass) {
        return $('.' + borderClass);
    });

    value.forEach(function (borderClass, index) {
         console.log(borderClasses[index], value[index]); // or just borderClass, but making a point here
    });

    return value;
})();
```

Comment: Whoa that is great! I was having so much trouble with ```.map```. I don't have the reputation to upvote you but thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an object would be better suited for your purpose, you can then retrieve the nodes just by writing e.g. myNodes["shadow"]

```
var makeArrays = (function() {
    var myNodes = {
      "inner-border":null, 
      "middle-border":null, 
      "outer-border":null, 
      "shadow":null};

     $.each(Object.keys(myNodes), function(index, value) {
        makeClassName =  "." + value;
        myNodes[value] = $( makeClassName );
      });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can store result in `array` and return it, so you can access to the list of selectors returned when you want.

**Full JS :**

```
var makeArrays = (function() {
    var selectedElements = {};
    var borderClasses = ["inner-border", "middle-border", "outer-border", "shadow"];

    $.each(borderClasses, function(index, value) {
        selectedElements[value] = $("."+value);
    });

    return selectedElements;
})();
```

Access to the elements selected by class :

```
makeArrays["inner-border"]; //will return selected element with class inner-border
makeArrays["shadow"]; //will return selected element with class shadow
```

Take a look at **[working examle](https://jsfiddle.net/enyfcwmv/2/)**.

Comment: You shouldn't be treating a JavaScript array like an associative array, if you're going to generate an associative array, use `var myArray = {};` which is really a misnomer anyway.